# How to resolve circular dependency in compilation of node modules?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, yarnpkg, circular-dependency, yarn-workspaces

I am using yarn workspaces and have a project (proj1) which uses a library I wrote (proj2), which had been initialised with create-react-library when I started it. My library uses visx in some of the components. Everything was fine until I added the last line in my index.js file, exporting another component that is build with visx:

```
export { ConfigField } from './ConfigField';
export { ConfigPage } from './ConfigPage';
export { SaveButton } from './SaveButton';
export { PageLoadingIndicator } from './PageLoadingIndicator';
export { UsersPage } from './UsersPage';
export { AnalyticValue } from './AnalyticValue';
export { DonutChart } from './DonutChart';
export { SingleValueDonutChart } from './SingleValueDonutChart';
export { Alert } from './Alert';
export { FormDialog } from './FormDialog';
export { TimeSeriesChart } from './TimeSeriesChart';
```

Somehow, after the addition of this export, when building proj2 a circular dependency is created. I suspect this is to do with compiling to have CJS imports.

```
PS C:\usr\git\proj2> yarn
yarn install v1.22.5
warning package.json: No license field
[1/4] Resolving packages...
success Already up-to-date.
$ run-s build
yarn run v1.22.5
warning package.json: No license field
$ microbundle-crl --no-compress --format modern,cjs
Circular dependency: ..\node_modules\@visx\axis\esm\index.js -> ..\node_modules\@visx\axis\esm\axis\Axis.js -> ..\node_modules\@visx\axis\esm\axis\AxisRenderer.js -> ..\node_modules\@visx\axis\esm\index.js
Non-existent export 'TextProps' is imported from ..\node_modules\@visx\text\esm\types.js
Error: 'TextProps' is not exported by ..\node_modules\@visx\text\esm\types.js, imported by ..\node_modules\@visx\text\esm\Text.js

at C:\usr\git\proj1\node_modules\@visx\text\esm\Text.js:8:9

 6: import useText from './hooks/useText';
 7: import { TextProps } from './types';
 8: export { TextProps } from './types';
             ^
 9: var SVG_STYLE = {
10:   overflow: 'visible'

error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
ERROR: "build" exited with 1.
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/install for documentation about this command.
```

How can I fix this circular dependency? Is there a plugin I should be using?

Answer (score 0):

Solved. The problem was actually pretty basic. I realised I was importing from `@visx/axis` without having it explicitly in my `package.json`.  After adding explicitly, it works.